# How to parse output of .serialize('json', data) from Django in HTML

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to loop through a serialized JSON object and display it as a list, but instead of listing the attributes I want, the loop runs over each individual character in the JSON string. When I do the same with a list of dicts it works. What am I doing wrong?

## Ptyhon code:

```
 def menu(request):
    # This is the object that I want to parse
    dishes = Dish.objects.all()
    dishes_ser = serializers.serialize('json', dishes)

    # This list is copy-pasted directly from the output of the serialized query 
    to see if I could get that to work
    check = [
        {"model": "orders.dish", "pk": 1, "fields": {"dish": "Pizza"}},
        {"model": "orders.dish", "pk": 3, "fields": {"dish": "Sub"}},
        {"model": "orders.dish", "pk": 5, "fields": {"dish": "Pasta"}},
        {"model": "orders.dish", "pk": 6, "fields": {"dish": "Salad"}},
        {"model": "orders.dish", "pk": 7, "fields": {"dish": "Dinner platter"}}
    ]

    context = {
    'dishes': dishes_ser,
    'check': check,
    }

    return render(request, "menu.html",context)
```

## HTML

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Menu
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <a href="/">Home</a>

    Raw output of the check variable as received from Django:
    <br />
    <br />
        {{check}}
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <ul>
        {% for data in check  %}
            <li>{{ data.fields.dish }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No Dishes</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <br/>

    Raw output of the dishes variable as received from Django::
    <br />
    <br />
        {{dishes}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ul>
        {% for data in dishes  %}
            <li>{{ data.fields.dish }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No Dishes</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{%endblock%}
```

## Result

Screenshot from HTML page
[image: Screenshot from HTML page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you serialize using `serializer.serialize`, it returns a string. You need to convert it to a json object like this:

```
import json
json_data = json.loads(dishes_ser)
# then pass this as context
context = {
    'dishes': json_data,
    'check': check,
}
```

But, why would you need to do that when you can directly send the queryset to template and use it like this:

```
// context
context = {
    'dishes': Dish.objects.all(),
    'check': check,
}
// template
{% for data in dishes  %}
        <li>{{ data.dish }}</li>
{% empty %}
        <li>No Dishes</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ruddra! I want to pass some data into my javascript code as well, so I wanted to figure out how to generate valid JSON. Follow-up question: Is there an easy way to check what format an object is? The raw output of the two variables in my screenshot looks syntactically identical (except for single vs double quotes) which is why it looked valid to me in the first place thus adding to my confusion as to why it didn't work

Comment: you can use `isinstance(variable, dict)` or `type(variable)` to check the type of object